# Apache Alias not working in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I have installed Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16, all works.

I have a website sitting on localhost, this also works fine.

I need to be able to access files on a USB drive to use within the website.

I'm using PHP to access the USB drive and obtain information of files, this works fine, however the issue arises when I try to display an image on the web page.

I'm using the .htaccess file and trying to use mod_alias to add a folder on the USB drive into the website, here is the content on my .htaccess file

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Alias "/USB" "/mnt/sdb1/images"
    <Directory "mnt/sdb1/images">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

So I know the .htaccess file is working because it loads my index.php file as the main file when I go to LocalHost.

I know the file path of the USB drive is correct because the PHP script has accessed it and collected the image files to display on the page, so PHP uses scandir to get all of the images in a folder (/mnt/sdb1/images) and it echos to the page correctly to show the images, for example;

```
    <img src="/USB/image1.jpg" />
```

But the images aren't loading on the page itself and I presume it's because the Alias doesn't appear to be working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that you need to grant www-data access to the USB files.  Usually in Apache directories, you set the owner to something like:

```
chown root:www-data *
chmod 750 * (for directories)
chmod 640 * (for files)
```

But, you may not be able to do that on a USB drive (sorry, never dealt with USB), but if it is a particular group, you could add www-data to that group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <USBGroup> www-data
```

So, for example, I have a shared drive on my Virtual Machine (/media/sf_node), which I am guessing works a lot like a USB drive.  So when I run the following command:

```
ls -la /media/sf_node
```

I see:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Jan 27 11:10 web
```

That shows the group vboxsf for that directory.  Then I can do a:

```
usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Wouldn't the fact that I can access the drive via PHP mean that my permissions are good?

Comment: Nope.  it is about who PHP is when the code is executing and requires rights to the files.  When PHP is running under your username, it has your privileges, but when it is running under apache, it is www-data

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the following;

        sudo chown -R root:www-data /mnt/sdb1

However it said 'Operation not permitted'

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing you can't change it, because it is a mounted drive.  So the second usermod will probably do it, you are adding www-data to the group that owns the USB drive (which you have to figure out by looking at the directory permissions

Comment: See my updated answer for an example that works for a similarly mounted drive.

Comment: Hi Katie, I appreciate your help, unfortunately because of timescales I had to do it a different way, so I was unable to check if your solution worked, but I have marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks